# Deleting an object by passing its pointer as a parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have two classes:

In my .h file:

```
class A
{
    A();

 private:
 vector<B*> list;

 void deleteObject(B* i);

 }


class B
{
  B();
}
```

In my .cpp file:

```
void A::deleteObject(B* i)
{
    delete i;
}
```

However, Visual Studio underlines deleteObject in red and says that it's incompatible with the declaration in the header file

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: *"However, this is not right and I am not sure why"* - Neither are we, since you didn't tell us what you are trying to accomplish with all of this

Comment: I did not even run the program, but my Visual Studio underlined it in red and told me that the declaration is incompatible with the declaration in the .h file

Comment: Probably because when you define `class A` it doesn't have a clue what is `B` in your `vector<B*>` declaration.

Comment: @Rogus so how do you suggest this could be fixed? By creating an object of type B in class A?

Comment: Move the definition of `class B` before `class A`

Comment: @Rogus That actually worked! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `;` at the end of classes (after `}`)

In addition, if both classes are in the same file, you must place class B above class A

```
class B
{
    B();
};

class A
{
     A();    
     private:
         vector<B*> list;    
         void deleteObject(B* i);    
};
```

You can see this error-free code [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xJg0Th0d8IMjvT2Y)